# Windows Phone 8.1 Voice Recognition + NavigationService problems

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone 8.1 using Speech recognition.
At this moment, I want navigate in the application using voice commands. The application has a button to active the voice recognition.

My problem at this moment is in NavigationService.Navigate.
When I press the button, the application recognize my voice speech (like "Settings") but throws an exception in the NavigationService.

This happens when I run the application in my device (Nokia lumia 735).
When I use the emulator (8.1 wvga 4inch 512mb), the application works nice and the NavigationService works very well!

This app is a part of a school project, so I will be very glad if anyone can help me with it.

This is my code at this moment:

The button click code:

```
private async void btSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            recoWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI();


            // Query for a recognizer that recognizes French as spoken in France.
            IEnumerable<SpeechRecognizerInformation> language = from recognizerInfo in InstalledSpeechRecognizers.All
                                                                         where recognizerInfo.Language == "en-US"
                                                                         select recognizerInfo;

            // Set the recognizer to the top entry in the query result.
            recoWithUI.Recognizer.SetRecognizer(language.ElementAt(0));

            // Build a string array, create a grammar from it, and add it to the speech recognizer's grammar set.
            string[] triviaCategories = { "activity tracker", "bmi caculator", "meal calculator", "nutrition chart", "settings" };
            recoWithUI.Recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromList("categories", triviaCategories);

            // Display text to prompt the user's input.
            recoWithUI.Settings.ListenText = "Say an option: ";

            // Display an example of ideal expected input.
            recoWithUI.Settings.ExampleText = "Activity Tracker\n @BMI Calculator\n Meal Calculator\n Nutrition Chart\n Settings";

            // Deactivate the readout of recognized text to the user.
            recoWithUI.Settings.ReadoutEnabled = true;

            // Load the grammar set and start recognition.
            SpeechRecognitionUIResult result = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

            //  Handle the caputed voice
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.RecognitionResult.Text))
            {
                recoWithUI.Dispose();
                VoiceComandsRecognition(result.RecognitionResult.Text.ToString());
            }
            else
                return;

        }
```

and the code for the method that handles the recognized string:

```
public void VoiceComandsRecognition(string CapturedVoice)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (CapturedVoice)
                {
                    case "activity tracker":
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ActivityTracker.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;
                    case "bmi calculator":
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/BMIcalculator.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;
                    case "meal calculator":
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MealCalculator.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;
                    case "nutrition chart":
                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/NutritionChart.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                        break;
                    case "settings":
                         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WinHealth;component/Pages/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                         break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao reconhecer o comando. "+e.ToString());
            }
    }
```

this is the exception:

> {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, String s)
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.UpdateMargin(Thickness region, PageOrientation orientation)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.OnVisibleRegionChange(Object sender, VisibleRegionChangeEventArgs args)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.System.Windows.Controls.IFrame.InternalOnVisibleRegionChange(Object sender, VisibleRegionChangeEventArgs args)
>      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Frame.FireEventHandler[T](EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender, T args)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.set_VisibleRegionInPhysicalPixels(RECT value)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.UpdateCurrentVisualState()
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.InternalUpdateOrientationAndMarginForPage(PhoneApplicationPage visiblePage)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.System.Windows.Controls.IFrame.InternalUpdateOrientationAndMarginForPage(IPhoneApplicationPage visiblePage)
>      at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
>      at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)}

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: @aloisdg I have updated the quest is the exception.
Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Can you start to try [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/exception-error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component) ?

Comment: Thank you for the url. I will try as soon as I get home. Thank you

Comment: @aloisdg it doesnt solve my problem.
I think the problem is aimed due to async button event.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed Bug in Windows Phone. Microsoft will fix it in 6-12 months they have told me.

Comment: Do you have a reference, such as a link to a Connect post?

Comment: I didn't find anything about it. Do you have something to prove that?

Comment: I want navigate through pages using the caputered voice commands. How I can do that??? Is this possible??

Comment: Do you have any news about your problem?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a4d6801-84a2-4a9e-bc2c-5dc516eab735/lumia-930-error-hresult-efail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required